# Critical Error when installing Civicrm on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

I'm trying to install Civicrm 5.64.3, using steps outlined on Civicrm's [installation guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/). I tried ftp upload the zip file and extract and also trying to add the zip file through the Wordpress/plugin instance. but it fails when I click "activate" in Wordpress. I clicked the "activate" in the /wp-admin/plugins.php page. It doesn't appear to run and the next page shows the error "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.".

Following this error, the site (entire html) is not accessible. The only way I could reset the access is to logon to my cPanel, go to file manager and rename the plugin folder to another name. Log back in to Wordpress and then rename the plugin folder back to original name in the file manager.

How can I troubleshot this?

I am running my site on Wordpress, hosted on hostgator.com. Server appears to be running PHP version 7.4.33 and MysSQL version 5.6.41-84.1.

Comment: Hi! Welcome. I don't think you'll get an answer to this question because it's too vague. Try adding more details.

Comment: I tried the installation step using the CiviCRM for wordpress version 5.65.2 files, it still does not work. Any feedback?